# Building Xamarin.Forms iOS project from command line with msbuild

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, msbuild

I'm trying to build a Xamarin.Forms iOS project via command line for CI/CD purposes directly on macOS:

```
msbuild C4S_MobileApp.iOS/C4S_MobileApp.iOS.csproj /restore /p:Platform=iPhone /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:Configuration="Release" /p:BuildProjectReferences="false"
```

The problem is the shared app project which I avoid rebuilding with `/p:BuildProjectReferences="false"` and whose .dll can't be found:

```
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file '/Users/c4s/Projects/c4s_refactored/c4s-refactored-mobile-app/C4S_MobileApp/bin/iPhone/Release/netstandard2.1/C4S.MobileApp.dll' could not be found [/Users/c4s/Projects/c4s_refactored/c4s-refactored-mobile-app/C4S_MobileApp.iOS/C4S_MobileApp.iOS.csproj]
```

MSBuild assumes the .dll in `C4S_MobileApp/bin/iPhone/Release/netstandard2.1/` but it's in `C4S_MobileApp/bin/Release/netstandard2.1`. An ugly solution would be to copy the C4S.MobileApp.dll to that location. Building without `/p:BuildProjectReferences="false"` works because msbuild then creates `C4S_MobileApp/bin/iPhone/Release/netstandard2.1/C4S.MobileApp.dll`

I added the parameter `/p:AssemblySearchPaths="C4S_MobileApp/bin/Release/netstandard2.1"` to msbuild command and also added `<AssemblySearchPaths>C4S_MobileApp/bin/Release/netstandard2.1;$(AssemblySearchPaths)</AssemblySearchPaths>` to the C4S_MobileApp.iOS.csproj file under Release|iPhone configuration but it seems to be ignored by msbuild.

Folder structure:
c4s-refactored-mobile-app/
-> C4S_MobileApp/
-> C4S_MobileApp.iOS/

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: You could firstly build the project in IDE to check if there is some existing issues (like configuration or code logic error ) . Then delete the folder `bin` and `obj ` and try again .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thanks for your answer. I can successfully build it with Visual Studio for Mac. Unfortunately same error after deleting bin and obj folders and building via command line. Building with IDE doesn't create C4S_MobileApp/bin/iPhone/.... so they're handling the path somehow internally like I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a bug in Xamarin.iOS: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10308